# Why is atomize not working with Gatsby JS (react)?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to use Atomize (https://atomizecode.com/) with Gatsby JS (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) and while it is successfully installed, the atomize components are not being rendered to the page.

I am trying to import a button to start "Hey", and while it renders something it is not the standard button component. Also, even though the button component is imported, I get the warning that reads it is not being used.

I am wrapping atomize around gatsby app by the following way:

```
import React from "react"
import { StyleReset } from "atomize"

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <>
    <StyleReset />
    {element}
  </>
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install styletron toolkit?

According to their [docs](https://atomizecode.com/docs/react/setup) it's a dependency and looking at their `package.json` it's defined under peerDependencies which means it won't get installed along with atomize.

[Styletron's docs](https://www.styletron.org/getting-started/#with-gatsby) sugggets using [gatsby-plugin-styletron](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-styletron/) for Gatsby.
Hope that helps.